# How to create the letter O with Clip Path

Tags: css, clip-path

[image]

I know how to get a circle with:

```css
clip-path: ellipse(25% 25% at 50% 50%);
```

But how do I punch a hole in it?

Comment: why? give your element a border-radius and a border

Comment: Hi, is this a general question about 'punching a hole in an element' or is it specifically about a circle?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm trying to make the shape of the letter "O".